# Equivalence between trace and Euclidean norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, trace

In the paper ["On best approximate solutions of linear matrix equations"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100030929), there is a very small equivalence I don't know where it comes from.

Let $A$ be a matrix (either real or complex), and $\|A\|$ be "the sum of the squares of the moduli of the elements of $A$" (sic; I believe it's the Euclidean norm of $A$), and $tr(\cdot)$ is the trace operator. I want to prove that $\|A\| = tr(A^{*}A)$.

I attempted to check this with $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, but $\|A\| = 30$ and $tr(A*A) = 29$.

What am I doing wrong? I think $*$ is the matrix multiplication operator, but it could also be the generalized inverse.

Comment: As Bye_World wrote in now-deleted answer, the notation $A^*A$ means the product of the conjugate-transpose of $A$ and of $A$ itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not $A*A$, it's $A^*A$ where $A^*$ is the transpose of $A$.  If you calculate $\operatorname{tr}(A^*A)$ (called the Frobenius norm$^\dagger$) you'll find that it equals $\|A\|$.

$^\dagger$: Technically this is the square of the Frobenius norm.